# У меня есть натуральное число?

Tags: c++

Есть натуральное число которое вводится с клавиатуры.
Нужно узнать количество его цифр кратных z1,z2,z3.

Сейчас считает некоректно

```
int a, z1,z2,z3;
cout << "The enter a ";
cin >> a;
int count = 0;
cin >> z1;
cin >> z2;
cin >> z3;
for (int i = 1; i < a; i++) {
    if (a % z1 == 0 && a % z2 == 0 && a % z3 == 0) {
        count++;    
    }
}
cout << count;
```

Comment: "Сейчас считает некоректно" - еще бы! Разве Вы "цифры" проверяете на кратность?

Comment: а что я проверяю?

Comment: если знаете помогите кодом )

Comment: Сначала внятно сформулируйте, что Вам нужно.

Comment: Игор, есть натуральное число...нужно узнать количество его цифр кратных z1,z2,z3.

Comment: Описание вопроса бредовое, что значит "количество цифр натурального числа"? Вы хотели сказать "все числа меньше натурального числа"?

Comment: Судя по всему, нужно просто поменять `if (a % z1 == 0 && a % z2 == 0 && a % z3 == 0)` на `if (i % z1 == 0 && i % z2 == 0 && i % z3 == 0)`

Comment: Вы смотрели на результат?

Comment: Я уже сказал, формулировка вашего вопроса оставляет желать лучшего. Я и люди выше могут только **догадываться**, какой результат вы хотите получить.

Comment: количество цифр любого числа является константным значением. Что узнать не понятно...

Comment: А для чего вы, собственно, дублируете свой аккаунт и задаете второй раз такой же вопрос с точно таким же плохим оформлением? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/887520/%D0%95%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-a-20-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB

Answer (score 1):

есть число 1234

чтобы узнать 4 цифру: 1234 % 10

чтобы узнать 3 цифру: (1234 % 100) / 10

чтобы узнать 2 цифру: (1234  / 100) % 10

чтобы узнать 1 цифру: 1234  / 1000

Comment: нет "цифры" 1234

Comment: @Igor Ну, в теории, при использовании системы счисления с достаточно большим основанием, может потребоваться использовать больше одного символа для записи цифр. :)

Comment: @Igor он имел в виду число